# Reloading vs Refreshing page with jquery on shared host

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

[image]

I am working with codeigniter and jquery. I am using ajax to send some info to a codeigniter function to perform a db operation , in order to update the page.

```
                  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: BASE_URL+"Update/update",
                        data:{ i : searchIDs, m : message },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);                              

                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            alert("REFRESHING..");

                         window.location.href = "pan_controller/reply";
                        }
                });
```

After the operation is complete I want to reload the page. This works normally in locally on my WAMP. However when I deploy to a shared host I usually have to reload the page manually, (using the reload button in the browser -- screenshot above). I see no errors in firebug. I've tried a variety of fixes but have recently started to wonder if this is a caching issue on my shared hosting server. If so is there a better way to reload using jquery rather than just redirect so as to avoid a cache on the shared host?

Comment: You can use ajaxComplete() method or add " window.location.href = "pan_controller/reply"; " on ajax success instead of on ajax complete.

Comment: is ajaxComplete() different from what I have above (I don't know much jquery). I tried the second thing and it didn't work.

Comment: This event behaves the same as the complete event and will be triggered every time an Ajax request finishes.

Comment: Use location.reload(true); to reload the page.

Comment: I tried window.location.reload(true) = "pan_controller/reply"; doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you established that the `complete` function is running in those cases when the page doesn't reload? If so then I think you are right, it's a caching problem.

You can try adding a timestamp parameter to the end of the `window.location.href` value to make it unique each time and avoid any issues with caching, although a better approach would be to send the correct headers back with the response, so that the browser knows not to cache that page.

```
window.location.href = "pan_controller/reply?t=" + (new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: Hi codebox, I can see "REFRESHING.." in my browser window, so I assume that complete is running. Can you tell me more about sending the correct headers with jquery, I assume you mean "no-cache" ? - Bill

Comment: Thank you , this does work . You've solved a problem that has been plaguing me for days!

Comment: glad that fixed it, here's a good article on caching: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CONTROL